# I have a project in college and I do some of the requirements

Tags: c++, project, variable-assignment

****my project talk about Shape hierarchy for every shape needs Inheritance, Polymorphism and Files I/0**

**I did a simple thing of the requirements, but I did not do it 100%, such as requirements 1, 2, 3 or requirements 6 and 7, so I sent all the requirements, please help me****

1. All classes must have a color and name attributes, both of a string type and stored in the base class (Shape).
2. All 2D shapes must have area and perimeter attributes, both of double type and stored in their base class (Sahpe2D).
3. All 3D shapes must have surfaceArea and volume attributes, both of double type and stored in their base class (Shape3D),
4. readData(), print(), printToFile(ofstream &output), readFromFile(ifstream &input) functions must be implemented in all classes (base and derived), taking into consideration they will be used for polymorphism,
5. computeArea() and computePerimeter() functions must be implementer in all 2D shape classes (including their base class), taking into consideration their use in polymorphism,
6. computeSurfaceArea() and computeVolume() functions must be implemented in all 3D shape classes (including their base class), taking into consideration their use in polymorphism,

Requirements

1. For every class, you need to build a default/parametrized constructor,
2. The default constructors set the objects' data members to 1.0,
3. Parametrized constructors are used to set objects' data members using the values passed to the objects during instantiation
4. readData() function is used to read all the object's data members from the user
5. print() function is used to print all object's data to the screen,
6. Your program must be able to write all objects' data to the binary file "Shapes.dat", using the printToFile functions,
7. Your program should be able to read and append to the "Shapes.dat" file as needed, using the readFromFile functions,
8. Your main file must be able to store/retrieve data to/from output/input files depending on the user's choice,
9. It is not known how many objects will be added or their order of addition.

//Shapes.h

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    string color, name;
    Shape()
    {
        cout << "Base Class is Shape for this element . \n";
    }
};


//Shape2D.h

#pragma once

#include"shapes.h"
    class Shape2D : public Shape {
    public:

        double area, perimeter;
        Shape2D()
        {
            cout << "Parent Class is Shape2D for this element .\n";
        }
    };
//Shape3D.h

#pragma once

 #include"shapes.h"
    class Shape3D : public Shape {
    public:

        Shape3D()
        {
            cout << "Parent Class is Shape3D for this element .\n";
        }
    };
//Square.h

#include"shapes2D.h"
    class Square : public Shape2D {

    public:
        Square()
        {
            cout << "Calculating square area and perimeter \n";
        }
        void computeArea(double side)
        {
            double area;
            area = side * side;
            print("Area", area);
            printToFile("Area", area);
        }
        void computePerimeter(double side) {
            double perimeter;
            perimeter = 4 * side;
            print("Perimeter", perimeter);
            printToFile("Perimeter", perimeter);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Square = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Square = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Triangle.h


#include"shapes2D.h"
    class Triangle : public Shape2D {

    public:
        Triangle()
        {
            cout << "This is a Triangle\n";
        }
        void computeArea(double base, double height) {
            double area;
            area = (height * base) / 2;
            print("Area", area);
            printToFile("Area", area);
        }
        void computePerimeter(double base, double height) {}
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Triangle = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Triangle = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Sphere.h

#include"shapes3D.h"

    class Sphere : public Shape3D {

    public:
        Sphere()
        {
            cout << "This is a Sphere\n";
        }
        void computeSurfaceArea(double radius) {
            double area;
            area = 4 * 3.14 * radius * radius;
            print("Area", area);
            printToFile("Area", area);
        }
        void computeVolume(double radius) {
            double perimeter;
            perimeter = (4 / 3) * (3.14 * radius * radius * radius);
            print("Perimeter", perimeter);
            printToFile("Perimeter", perimeter);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Sphere = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Sphere = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Hexagon.h

#include"shapes2D.h"
    class Hexagon : public Shape2D {

    public:
        Hexagon()
        {
            cout << "This is a Hexagon\n";
        }
        void computeArea(double side) {
            double area;
            area = 3 * sqrt(3) * side * side / 2;
            print("Area", area);
            printToFile("Area", area);
        }
        void computePerimeter(double side) {
            double perimeter;
            perimeter = 6 * side;
            print("Perimeter", perimeter);
            printToFile("Perimeter", perimeter);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Hexagon = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Hexagon = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Cylinder.h

#include"shapes3D.h"

    class Cylinder : public Shape3D {

    public:
        Cylinder()
        {
            cout << "This is a Cylinder\n";
        }
        void computeSurfaceArea(double radius, double height) {
            double area;
            area = (2 * 3.14 * radius) * (radius + height);
            print("Surface Area", area);
            printToFile("Surface Area", area);
        }
        void computeVolume(double radius, double height) {
            double volume;
            volume = 3.14 * radius * radius * height;
            print("Volume", volume);
            printToFile("Volume", volume);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Cylinder = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Cylinder = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Cube.h

#include"shapes3D.h"
    class Cube : public Shape3D {

    public:
        Cube()
        {
            cout << "This is a Cube\n";
        }
        void computeSurfaceArea(double side) {
            double area;
            area = 6 * side * side;
            print("Surface Area", area);
            printToFile("Surface Area", area);
        }
        void computeVolume(double side) {
            double volume;
            volume = side * side * side;
            print("Volume", volume);
            printToFile("Volume", volume);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Cube = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Cube = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Cone.h

#include"shapes3D.h"
#include<cmath>
    class Cone : public Shape3D {
        double radius, height;
    public:
        Cone()
        {
            cout << "This is a Cone\n";
        }
        void computeSurfaceArea(double radius, double height) {
            double area;
            area = 3.14 * radius * (radius + sqrt(radius * radius + height * height));
            print("Surface Area", area);
            printToFile("Surface Area", area);
        }
        void computeVolume(double radius, double height) {
            double volume;
            volume = (3.14 * radius * radius * height) / 3;
            print("Volume", volume);
            printToFile("Volume", volume);
        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Cone = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Cone = " << y << "\n";

        }
    };
//Circle.h


#include"shapes2D.h"
    class Circle : public Shape2D{
        double radius;
    public:
        Circle()
        {
            cout << "Calculating circle area and perimeter \n";
        }
        void computeArea(double r)
        {
            double area;
            area = 3.14 * r * r;
            print("Area", area);
            printToFile("Area", area);

        }
        void computePerimeter(double r) {
            double perimeter;
            perimeter = 2 * 3.14 * r;
            print("Perimeter", perimeter);
            printToFile("Perimeter", perimeter);

        }
        void print(string x, double y)
        {
            cout << x << " of Square = " << y << "\n";
        }
        void printToFile(string x, double y)
        {
            ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("shapes.dat");
            if (!ofs) {
                cout << "Error opening file" << endl;

            }
            cout << "Shapes.dat file updated .";
            ofs << x << " of Circle = " << y << "\n";

        }

    };
//main.cpp


#include"Cone.h"
#include"Cube.h"
#include"Cylinder.h"
#include"Hexagon.h"
#include"sphere.h"
#include"square.h"
#include"Triangle.h"
#include "Circle.h"

int main()
{
    Cylinder a;
    Cube b;
    Cone c;



    double r, side, base, height;
    int n;
    cout << "Select any Number to calculate : ";
    cout << "1. Circle \n";
    cout << "2. Square\n";
    cout << "3. Triangle\n";
    cout << "4. Hexagon\n";
    cout << "5. Sphere\n";
    cout << "6. Cube\n";
    cout << "7. Cylinder\n";
    cout << "8. Cone\n";
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 1) {
        Circle obj1;
        cout << "Circle Radius";
        cin >> r;
        obj1.computeArea(r);
        obj1.computePerimeter(r);
    }

    if (n == 2) {
        Square obj2;
        cout << "Square Side";
        cin >> side;
        obj2.computeArea(side);
        obj2.computePerimeter(side);
    }

    if (n == 3) {
        Triangle obj3;
        cout << "Triangle Base";
        cin >> base;
        cout << "Triangle Height";
        cin >> height;
        obj3.computeArea(base, height);
        // obj3.computePerimeter(base,height) ;
    }

    if (n == 4) {
        Hexagon obj4;
        cout << "Hexagon Side";
        cin >> side;
        obj4.computeArea(side);
        obj4.computePerimeter(side);
    }

    if (n == 5) {
        Sphere obj5;
        cout << "Sphere Radius";
        cin >> r;
        obj5.computeSurfaceArea(r);
        obj5.computeVolume(r);
    }

    if (n == 6) {
        Cube obj6;
        cout << "Cube Side";
        cin >> side;
        obj6.computeSurfaceArea(side);
        obj6.computeVolume(side);
    }

    if (n == 7) {
        Cylinder obj7;
        cout << "Cylinder Radius";
        cin >> r;
        cout << "Cylinder Height";
        cin >> height;
        obj7.computeSurfaceArea(r, height);
        obj7.computeVolume(r, height);
    }

    if (n == 8) {
        Cone obj8;
        cout << "Cone Radius";
        cin >> r;
        cout << "Cone Height";
        cin >> height;
        obj8.computeSurfaceArea(r, height);
        obj8.computeVolume(r, height);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A 500 line code example is a bad idea, and frankly I don't know how you got this past the server's code-to-description ratio filter. Surely you can minimize the code and still demonstrate the same misbehaviour? Doing so will likely reduce the noise around the problem to the point where you can  spot and fix the mistake yourself. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Comment: `Shape` has a default constructor, but not a parameterized constructor. Eg: `Shape(string color, string name): color(color), name(name) { cout << "Base Class is Shape for this element . \n";}`

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things going on here.

1. You are trying to include header files all over the place. I dont know why you want/need them. It's fine (if you have those files defined somewhere) but for a simple case of defining some classes one monolithic file is ok.
2. You haven't satisfied the problem statement. It said "default/parametrized constructor" you have default constructors for each i.e. 'myClass()' but no parameterized one ex 'myClass(int heigh, int width)...' so you need to implement those so you can initialize shapes at construction time instead of setting them later.
3. The formatting is all over the place, I would recommend cleaning that up.

To your main question: "it appears to me that the classes are not defined What is the problem?"

You have defined classes, this is a class definition:

```
class Shape 
{ 
public: 
    Shape()
    {      
        cout << "Base Class is Shape for this element . \n";
    } 
private:
string color, name;
};
```

Down in main Shape myshape; is creating an object of type shape.

Here is a easy write up to follow as well:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-classes-and-objects/

Comment: On 1: I think the asker just dumped many files into one big-ass code block. It's the many files bit that's causing their trouble.